# DelegateCall for multi transaction for minting, approving and putting on a marketplace of NFT

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I have been trying delegateCalls to make a contract that can execute multiple transactions. My main goal is to achieve minting an NFT, approving the NFT to a marketplace and then putting on sale on the approved marketplace but using a single transaction.

```
function mintAndPutOnMarketPlace(address payable mintingRecipient, string memory mintingUri, address marketOriginContract, uint256 marketSaleAmount, address marketplaceContractAddress)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint256)
    {
        address collection = marketOriginContract;
        address marketplace = marketplaceContractAddress;

        uint256 tokenId = delegateMint(collection, mintingRecipient, mintingUri);
        delegateApprove(collection, marketplaceContractAddress);
        delegatePutOnSale(marketplace, marketOriginContract, tokenId, marketSaleAmount);

        return tokenId;
    }

    function delegateMint(address collection, address recipient, string memory uri) internal returns(uint256 tokenId){

        ICollection icollection = ICollection(collection);
        tokenId = icollection.mint(payable(recipient),uri);

        return tokenId;
    }

    function delegateApprove(address collection, address operator) internal{

        bool toApprove = true;

        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("setApprovalForAll(address,bool)", operator, toApprove);

        bool success;

        assembly {
            let output := mload(0x40)
            success := delegatecall(
                gas(),
                collection,
                add(payload, 0x20),
                mload(payload),
                0,
                0
            )
        }

    }

    function delegatePutOnSale(address marketplace, address _originContract, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _amount) internal{

        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("setSalePrice(address,uint256,uint256)",_originContract, _tokenId, _amount);

        bool success;

        assembly {
            let output := mload(0x40)
            success := delegatecall(
                gas(),
                marketplace,
                add(payload, 0x20),
                mload(payload),
                0,
                0
            )
        }

    }
```

I am currently stuck in this approach the minting is done but the other 2 process having  delegate calls are giving errors

This is a sample transaction of the entire scenario

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xee62986c8d726270b90f110b6cc2584752388fa32bd8b25e25b6e87c4aaa7eea

Comment: were you able to overcome this issue?